# Verify method called with parameter and call order

Tags: c#, moq

I have to verify if a method within a target method get called with a sequence of parameters, like below. For example, how to verify that `RepairCar()` is called with `car` parameter first, rather than `car2`.

```
[TestClass]
    public class TestMethodParam
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Mock<ICarService> carService = new Mock<ICarService>(MockBehavior.Strict);

            var car = new Car
                {
                    Name = "1"
                };

            var car2 = new Car
            {
                Name = "2"
            };

            var carManager = new CarManager(carService.Object);

            //act
            carManager.Serve();

            //assert: 
            carService.Verify(c => c.RepairCar(It.Is<Car>(actualCar => actualCar.Name == car.Name)), Times.Once());
            carService.Verify(c => c.RepairCar(It.Is<Car>(actualCar => actualCar.Name == car2.Name)), Times.Once());



        }
    }

    public interface ICarService
    {
        void RepairCar(Car car);
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    public class CarManager
    {
        private ICarService carService;

        public CarManager(ICarService carService)
        {
            this.carService = carService;
        }
        public void Serve()
        {
            var car = new Car
                {
                    Name = "1"
                };

            carService.RepairCar(car);

            var car2 = new Car
            {
                Name = "2"
            };

            carService.RepairCar(car2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to achieve this is to use a callback and use some list to remember the call sequence.

```
[TestClass]
    public class TestMethodParam
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var repairCarCalls = new List<string>();
            Mock<ICarService> carService = new Mock<ICarService>();

            var car = new Car
            {
                Name = "1"
            };

            var car2 = new Car
            {
                Name = "2"
            };

            carService.Setup(c => c.RepairCar(It.IsAny<Car>())).Callback<Car>(c => repairCarCalls.Add(c.Name));

            var carManager = new CarManager(carService.Object);

            //act
            carManager.Serve();

            //assert: 
            var expectedCalls = new[] { car.Name, car2.Name };
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedCalls, repairCarCalls);
        }
    }
```